# Running some parquet-tools commands using Java -jar

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, parquet

In order to see the content of my parquet file, I tried running some parquet-tools commands using version 1.9.1 and version
1.6.1 and was quite surprised to see that the newer parquet-tools doesn't
work for me at all:

I want to run the parquet-tool using java -jar command. Bellow the commands I tried and the result obtained

- java -jar parquet-tools-1.9.1-SNAPSHOT.jar meta /tmp/test.parquet
- java -jar parquet-tools-1.9.1-SNAPSHOT.jar cat /tmp/test.paruet

The obtained result for both commands:

- org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration
- org/apache/hadoop/fs/Path

Can someOne guides me with sample example to resolve this.
Thansk in advance

Comment: Please can you post the actual error message you saw?

Comment: @BenWatson Watson . I didn't get any error. I get "org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration" while executing "java -jar parquet-tools-1.9.1-SNAPSHOT.jar meta /tmp/test.parquet"

Comment: Add --debug and you will get a more verbose 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29724629/